# Cannot write in the Node.js prompt after using ng serve --open --port 4300

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm just trying out Angular for the very first time and I'm stuck.
I couldn't use the port 4200 anymore, so did the following:

```
ng serve --open --port 4200
```

It does its job but I can't type anything else into the console...

Idk whether it's helpful or not but here are the last few lines

```
Date: 2018-06-12T17:39:50.544Z - Hash: 63d507da2f6ad4d29150 - Time: 207ms 4 
unchanged chunks chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 10.8 kB [initial] 
[rendered] i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I guess its not.

The cursor is still blinking but nothing I tried did help...

Comment: Haha. I just tried every letter with Ctrl and as soon as I pressed Ctrl + C it asked me:Batchvorgang abbrechen (J/N)? Its German :( J/N stands for Yes and No. I pressed Yes and I could type again. But I'm quite sure there is a much simpler way of doing that. And have done a like foolish thing with that??? Is it kinda wrong?

Comment: CTRL + C stops the current ng serve. When you have used ng serve it automatically updates the running localhost each time you save in your IDE. You most of the time dont need to restart it. But if you do, just hit CTRL + C and afterwards write ng serve again.

Comment: In general CTRL + C is used to stop many ongoing actions in command line regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website has been served locally. If you go to `http://localhost:4200` within a browser it should show up. The blinking cursor means it is currently running - if you hit `Ctrl-C` it will stop the process.

Also the blinking cursor may indicate you are watching the code for changes, if you change a file it will recompile the served website with the changes.

If you want to issue other commands in the prompt you will have to open up a new command window, otherwise you must stop the process first.